# Best way to normalise to remove the effect of a variable

Tags: python, data-transformation, normalization

I have a forward citation column that gives me the number of times a patent is cited. However, it is obvious that it is affected by age since the older the patent is, the probability that it will be cited more compared to a newer patent that is granted years later. Hence, I would like to normalise the forward citation column by age. I decided that I should divide the forward citation count by the patent's age. Is that the best way? . I have read somewhere that we can use log transformation but I am not sure. The pdf of forward citation is shown if that is useful. The forward citation generally follows a lognormal distribution.

Can anyone help?

[image: Distribution]

Comment: This looks like a Poisson distribution. When you have a variable you want to scale by, this is called an offset in Poisson regression.

Comment: Hello, I wan to normalise by patent age. I have tried using this formula (normalised = forward citations/patent age).

Comment: You should be doing a Poisson distribution with an offset (IMHO). How to do this depends on the software you are using.

Comment: Have you plotted the age and the citation count in a scatterplot? How does it look? Can you post the graph here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only the total number of citations at time T (for example, as of today), it makes sense to adjust by the age of the patent to account for the fact that older patents had more time to receive citations. One complication is that the number of citations a patent receives is not a linear function of time. Some patents might receive a lot of citations right from the start, others might receive very few citations in the beginning yet gain more citations later. So, ideally you would need citation information for each year since publication to be able to compare these two patents. Granted, if this information is not available, then dividing by age is a reasonable approach. This division by age is a conceptual adjustment given your expert knowledge that the number of citations depends on age. So, it is unrelated to taking logs. You can take logs if you want, depending on your regression specification.